# Help to call boolean method on trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, validation

I need help to undestand how can I call and validate a method that returns boolean.

My method:

```
public static boolean ValidateField(){
    boolean IsValidValue=false;
    List<Account> accList= new List<Account>();
    for(Account acc : accList){
    if(acc.Name == 'Test'){
        IsValidValue= true;
    }
    }
    return IsValidValue;
}
```

My trigger:

```
trigger validateFieldTrigger on Account(before insert){
 if(Trigger.isInsert){
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
        if(!MyClass.ValidateField()){
            acc.AddError('The value is invalid');
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I need to display the message only if the name is different from Test, it is displaying in both scenarios.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a utility method like this:

```
public class MyUtility  {
    public static Boolean validateField(Account account){
        return account.Name == 'Test';
    }   
}
```

and call this from you Trigger context.

```
if(Trigger.isInsert){
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
        if(!MyUtility.validateField(acc)){
            acc.addError('The value is invalid');
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass a parameter on which the logic needs to run, like shown above. In your snippet there is no parameter being passed.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your `ValidateField` is always returning false as the `for` loop iterates through an empty list, always.

`MyClass` appears to be acting a "handler" to your `Account` trigger. You can just pass the `Trigger.new` context straight into your validation method.

```
trigger validateFieldTrigger on Account (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        MyClass.ValidateField(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Side note on your trigger while we are here. Ideally you should work with only ever one trigger per SObject. If you are following naming conventions, your trigger today reads as though you are creating (or plan to) use triggers for each business/techincal function.  I advise creating a single `AccountTrigger` handling many DML operations and your "handler" class sorting the business/technical functions.

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void ValidateField(List<Account> toValidate){
        for(Account acc : toValidate){
            if(acc.Name == 'Test'){
                acc.AddError('The value is invalid');
            }
        }
    }
}
```